# Appending to text file in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to append to a text file that starts off empty and every time the method `addStudent()` is called it would add a `student.toString()` line to the said file. I don't seem to get any exceptions but for some reason, after the method call, the file remains empty. Here is my code.

```
public void addStudent() {
        Student student = new Student();
        EditText fName = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        EditText lName = findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        EditText studentGpa = findViewById(R.id.gpa);
        String firstName = String.valueOf(fName.getText());
        String lastName = String.valueOf(lName.getText());
        String gpa = String.valueOf(studentGpa.getText());

        if(firstName.matches("") || lastName.matches("") || gpa.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please make sure none of the fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            double gpaValue = Double.parseDouble(gpa);
            student.setFirstName(firstName);
            student.setLastName(lastName);
            student.setGpa(gpaValue);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("students.txt",  MODE_APPEND);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                osw.write(student.toString());
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

What might be the problem here? The file `students.txt` itself is located in `assets` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`What might be the problem here? The file students.txt itself is located in assets folder`.

If it is in the assets folder then you should use AssetsManager top open an input stream to it. Files in the assets folder are readonly so trying to write to them does not make sense.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("students.txt",  MODE_APPEND);
```

That wil create a file in private internal memory of your app. The code looks ok. But it makes no sense trying to find the file on your phone with a file manager or other app as as said that is private internal memory of your app only.

You use a relative path with "studends.txt" and now you do not know where the file resides.

Well the file resides in the path indicated by `getFilesDir()`.

You could as well have used a full path with

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "students.txt");
```

and then open a FileOutputStream with

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be with the fact that 'assets' directory doesnt exists on phone. So if I understand you correctly you may checking the wrong file.

Comment: Then should I create the file on the phone and append to that one?

Comment: Actually this file can be already created if this code works. You can try find it on the phone or read it from code.