# How to read file from internal memory and assign variables to objects

Tags: java, android

I have a method that should theoretically read the text file located in the internal memory of the emulator and assign each line after the new line to its respected variable and afterward put the object in the hashmap, here is what I mean. The text file format is like so:

```
John
Doe
3.0

Jane
Doe
3.4
```

and so on, you get the idea. So I want the following method

```
public void updateList(Context context) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("students.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            Student student = new Student();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    if (student.getFirstName() == null) {
                        student.setFirstName(line.trim());
                    } else if (student.getLastName() == null) {
                        student.setLastName(line.trim());
                    } else if (String.valueOf(student.getGpa()) == null) {
                        student.setGpa(Double.parseDouble(line.trim()));
                        studentBag.put(student.getFirstName(), student);
                    } else {
                        student = new Student();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(studentBag.toString()); //print out to check contents of map
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

to assign first line after new line to firstName, second line to lastName and third line to gpa. Each blank line indicates a start of a new `Student` object. However `System.out.println(studentBag.toString());` comes back empty, what am I doing wrong here? I have the map defined like so `private HashMap<String, Student> studentBag = new HashMap<>();` and I call the `updateList()` on `onResume()` method like so in order to check if any students have been added or removed in other activity

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateList(this);
    }
```

Comment: This is probably not what you expect (from String.valueOf docs): if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; therefore your check `== null` is never true.

Comment: Hi, while you perform read/write on file prefer using JSON format with support of Jackson library which will help you to form objects of your data to operate more easily.

Comment: `read the text file located in the internal memory of the emulator ` What do you consider to be the internal memory of the emulator? The `assets` ? `getFilesDir()` or `getExternalFilesDirs()` ? How did you place the file there? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675452/appending-to-text-file-in-android/58678223#58678223